"Sending message to a Handler on a dead thread" warnings in a foreground service that gets location every second
I’m having an issue with a foreground service in my Android app. I’m encountering the following warning in the log:

Handler (com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zzi) {c19f288} sending
message to a Handler on a dead thread (Ask Gemini)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler
(com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zzi) {c19f288} sending message
to a Handler on a dead thread     at
android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:560)     at
android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:786)   at
android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:735)    at
android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:705)   at
android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:435)     at
com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.HandlerExecutor.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.3.0:1)
at
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ListenerHolder.notifyListener(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:2)
at
com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzdv.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@@21.2.0:2)
at
com.google.android.gms.location.zzv.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@@21.2.0:7)
at
com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@@21.2.0:3)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1344)     at
android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1275)

Code Context:
private val locationCallback: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {}
private val mHandlerThread = HandlerThread("locationUpdates").apply { start() }
private val mHandler = Handler(mHandlerThread.looper)

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    requestLocationUpdates()
}

private fun requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            createLocationRequest()
            val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                        val location = locationResult.lastLocation
                        if (location != null) {
                            val speedKmph = (location.speed * 3.6).roundToInt()
                            mSpeed = speedKmph
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                mLocationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                mHandler.looper // Use mHandler's looper
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Log the error or handle it appropriately
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {
        // Handle missing permissions
    }
}

Here’s a snippet of the relevant code where I request location updates in my foreground service:
private fun requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            createLocationRequest()
            val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                    // Handle location result
                }
            }
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                mLocationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                mHandlerThread.looper
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {
        // Handle missing permissions
    }
}

Issue:
The warning suggests that a Handler is attempting to send a message to a thread that has already been stopped or is in an invalid state. This could potentially lead to crashes or other issues in my service.
Questions:
How can I ensure that my Handler is correctly managed and not sending messages to a dead thread?
Is there a way to properly handle the lifecycle of Handler and HandlerThread in a foreground service to avoid this issue?
What changes should I make to my Handler and HandlerThread usage to prevent this error?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
AI fails to solve it.
Thanks in advance!

You should just be able to do Looper.getMainLooper() instead of creating a whole handler for it

Note that what you do in your code above and what @tyczj suggested do very different things.  His suggestion will run the callback on the UI thread.  Your code attempts to make a new thread and run it on that.  If you want a new thread, do not use his suggestion.  If you were doing this because it was the only way you knew to get a looper and are ok using the UI thread, then his suggestion is fine.

Hi, this is a foreground service, used to get the speed. It should run both in the background when the activity is hidden and also when the activity is shown. Will there be a problem if I will use the UI thread? It worked before for years but now I noticed the warnings. I can test it manually though and see if it works properly. The code I used before came from Google documentation.

A background thread is not the same as your app being in the background. What Gabe means is that if you need your go get the location in a background thread (ie. because you are doing some CPU intensive work with it) then you should not use what I suggested. Most cases getting the location on the UI thread is just fine. Since you said you go this from an example then just use the main thread like I suggested

It's not something that takes time, I'm just getting the speed and adjusting the volume and send a notification and broadcast the values back to the activity.

Yes it looks like the flow is not working correctly now when new parameters are broadcasted to the service from the activity. I will have to debug.

The thing is I don't kill any thread, I have the main activity and this service location updates thread. I don't know why these warnings are shown. I think the app acts with random problems now. The notification time is not updated and sometimes code is not executed or executed slowly after location updates.

I think i needed to add back the synchronized block that I removed before, it's not related to this change, it seems to work fine.
